# django Admin - Filter foreign key select depending on other choice in edit form (without jQuery)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a project which is administered by a super admin who puts in data for different companies.

Lets say, I have these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ContactPerson(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Item(models.Model):
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
     contact_person = models.ForeignKey(ContactPerson)
```

I need to ensure that I (in django admin) in the edit mode I only see contact persons which belong to the selected company.

Being not in the year 2005 anymore I want to avoid writing loads of super ugly jQuery code.

I guess I could overwrite the admin form for `Item`. But still I had to make the `contact_person` optional, so when I create a new `Item`, the list of contact persons need to be empty. Then I'd select a company, save it and go back to edit. Now the `contact_person` list would be filled and I could add somebody. But if I now change the comany, I'd have to remove all selected contact persons. Sure, I could to this in the form... but it looks SO hacky and not like a nice django solution.

Anybody got some fancy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, django provided me with a neat solution.

When you look at the `UserAdmin` class within the django code, you'll find a built-in way to handle a two-step creation process.

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during user creation
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

When the attribute `add_form` is set and the object has no id yet (= we are creating it), it takes a different form than usual.

I wrapped this idea in an admin mixin like this:

```
class AdminCreateFormMixin:
    """
    Mixin to easily use a different form for the create case (in comparison to "edit") in the django admin
    Logic copied from `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`
    """
    add_form = None

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Now, when I have dependent fields, I create a small form, containing all values independent of - in my case - `company` and a regular form containing everything.

```
@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(AdminCreateFormMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ItemEditForm
    add_form = ItemAddForm
    ...
```

Now I can customise the querysets of the dependent field in my edit form:

```
class ItemEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['contact_person'].queryset = ContactPerson.objects.filter(company=self.instance.company)
```

The only drawback is, that all dependent fields need to be **nullable** for the database. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to save it in the creation process.

Luckily, you can tell django that a field is required in the form but not on database level with `blank=False, null=True` in the model declaration.

Hope this helps somebody else as well!

Comment: what is AdminDisabledCompanyFieldMixin ?

Comment: @ufk Just a mixin I wrote, not relevant for the case. Sorry, forgot to remove this in the example.